# Table insert with different columns sequences in source and target tables

Tags: sql, insert

Looking for inserting data from Table A to Table B where the column sequence is different in Table A(source) and Table B(target). For example,

Table A:

```
| ID | Name | Salary |
| 1  | AAA  | 100    |
```

Table B:

```
| name | salary | id |
| AAA  | 100    |  1 |
```

I cannot hardcode the column names as I am trying to use this logic to load data dynamically for multiple tables.

Comment: And you trust the column names to always match?

Comment: yes, column names will always match

Comment: You could put both INSERT _and_ SELECT columns in alphabetical order. E.g. `INSERT INTO TableX (a, b, c) SELECT a, b, c FROM TableY`.

Comment: You should also include a little bit of what tools etc. you're using and what is your RDBMS. Otherwise you might not get the best advise.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Alphabetical order helped.